# Get userid in Route in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing

Please help me fix this, I have this code on my views

```
 <a class="btn " href="updatePayment/{{$runner->id }}">Update Payment</a>
```

How can I get that id to make it work on controller? I have this code on my controller

```
 public function updatePayment($id)
{
    //

    return $id;
}
```

and on my route is this

```
Route::get('updatePayment/{ id }', 'RunnersController@updatePayment');
```

and I have this error

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Please help.. Thank you

Comment: Check namespace of `RunnersController`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `$id` instead of `$runner->id`? What variable you're returning in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Router:

```
Route::get('updatePayment/{id}', 'RunnersController@updatePayment')->name('updatePayment');
```

blade:

```
<a class="btn " href={{route('updatePayment',$runner->id)}}>Update Payment</a>
```

Comment: @user3226367 your welcome..
 vote my answer, if it helps, thanks